# Writing large arrays to parquet in a streaming fashion?

Tags: .net, parquet

We are using ParquetSharp. We have schema which looks like this (ParquetSharp c# format):

```
 new Column[] {
  new Column<string>("measurement_name"),
  new Column<DateTime?>("timestamp"),
  new Column<float?[]>("data")
}
```

We sometimes need to write a large dataset to the data column - around 250 million values.

Can we write the entries in a streaming fashion? We get the data as an `IEnumerable<float?>`, but currently we have to convert them to a `float?[]` before writing, which causes OutOfMemory errors.

We are currently writing like this:

```
void WriteData(ParquetFileWriter writer1, IList<MyDataset> dataSets)
{

  using var rg1 = writer1.AppendRowGroup();
  using (var colWriter = rg1.NextColumn().LogicalWriter<string>())
  {
    colWriter.WriteBatch(dataSets.Select(c => c.MeasurementName).ToArray());
  }
  using (var colWriter = rg1.NextColumn().LogicalWriter<DateTime?>())
  {
    colWriter.WriteBatch(dataSets.Select(c => c.DateTime).ToArray());
  }
  using (var colWriter = rg1.NextColumn().LogicalWriter<float?[]>())
  {
    colWriter.WriteBatch(dataSets.Select(c => c.Data).ToArray());
  }
}
```

where MyDataset.Data is a `float?[]` property. But we would like to convert this to an `IEnumerable<float?>` - or similar?

Of course, we can reduce memory usage somewhat by converting to a stream of datasets and writing a new rowgroup for each of them, but sometimes we will get just one very large dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you are looking for but perhaps using a static extension may help?

```
public static class DataSetExtensions
{

    private static async IAsyncEnumerable<List<TModel>> FetchPartially<TModel>(this IList<TModel> data, int batchSize = 10)
    {
        var count = data.Count();
        var batches = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)count / batchSize);
        for (var i = 0; i < batches; i++)
        {
            var skip = i * batchSize;
            var take = Math.Min(batchSize, count - skip);
            yield return data.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var yourlargeDataset = new List<MyDataSet>();
await foreach(var smallDataset in yourlargeDataset.FetchPartially(100)) //100 items per time
{
   WriteData(riter1, smallDataset );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't really solve the problem, which is that the API apparently only allows me to write a full cell (all the float? values).